# Passing number type as React component property

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm just getting started with React on asp.net core 2.0 (React project type).  I'm having some trouble passing number types to my components.  For example if I attempt to pass a number type (id) I get the error:

TS) Type '{id: boolean;}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes...

```
import * as React from 'react';
interface HelloWorldProps{
  name: string
  id: number
}
export class Greeting extends React.Component<HelloWorldProps, any> {
  render() {
      return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
export default Greeting;
```

When I attempt to render the component I get a TS error here...

```
<HelloWorld id=1 />
```

Without the id property it works fine.

Comment: If passing property other than strings, you have to surround the value with `{}`.

Comment: I think @zer0chain is correct here - expanding slightly, the ID prop seems to be going through some JavaScript type coercion and coming out as a boolean, which fails the type check.

Comment: Thanks, actually figured it out after I posted question.

Answer (score 10):

You should surround the numeric value in curly braces as below -

```html
<HelloWorld id={1} />
```